# Displaying ListView (with all items visible) from the bottom of a screen when a condition is satisfied

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to display a `ListView` with some items when a URL response is received.

To display `ListView` from bottom what I have done is, I have put it at the end of LinearLayout(it's parent) with `visibility` set to `gone`.

Layout file :

```
</LinearLayout>
    .
    .
    .
    <!-- ListView at bottom -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/places_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I want to display `ListView`, I make it visible and translate it using animation as shown below :

```
// Show listView that displays a list of items
private void showListView() {

    ObjectAnimator animator = null;
    placeListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Display listView with animation 
    if (activeEditTextId == R.id.from_location) {

        animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(placeListView, "y", fromLocation.getY() + fromLocation.getHeight() + 5);

    } else if (activeEditTextId == R.id.to_location) {

        animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(placeListView, "y", toLocation.getY() + toLocation.getHeight() + 5);
    }

    animator.setDuration(2000);
    animator.start();

    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But the issue is that with this layout, `ListView` height is 37 only. I understand it is because  only that much height is available at the end for `ListView`.

But how to show `ListView` with it full size i.e. all items visible at once?

Comment: set your height with wrap_content..

Comment: @Segi Tried. Not solved.

Comment: what is the result for that.?

Comment: Same as using `match_parent`. Height is still 37 only.

Comment: then change your linear layout height.. because it use that parent size.

Comment: @Segi LinearLayout occupies the whole screen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32381/discussion-between-segi-and-akash)

Comment: put your whole xml file..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by calculating height of `ListView` dynamically when list's contents are changed and before displaying `ListView`.
Copying code from [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren.htm).

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 

    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```